# Import Multiple Images With Unknown Names

Tags: image, matlab, file, file-io, matlab-cvst

I need to import multiple images (10.000) in Matlab (2013b) from a subdirectory of the predefined directory of Matlab.

I don't know the exact names of the images.

I tried this:

```
file = dir('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train');
NF = length(file);

for k = 1 : NF
    img = imread(fullfile('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train', file(k).name));
end
```

But it throws this error though I ran it with the Admin privileges:

```
Error using imread (line 347)
Can't open file "C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train\." for reading;
you may not have read permission.
```

Comment: "C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train\." doesn't seem like the path to image file to me.

Comment: I have multiple images in this subdirectory. I literally copied & pasted code from another thread

Comment: I was trying to point out that your file paths are not what you think they are. See the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "dir" command returns the virtual directory elements "." (self directory) and ".." parent, as your error message shows.

A simple fix is to use a more specific `dir` call, based on your image types, perhaps:

```
file = dir('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train\*.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of dir. The first two "files" are `.` and `..`, which is similar to the behaviour of the windows dir command.

```
file = dir('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train');
NF = length(file);

for k = 3 : NF
    img = imread(fullfile('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train', file(k).name));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In R2013b you would have to do

```
file = dir('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train\*.jpg');
```

If you have R2014b with the Computer Vision System Toolbox then you can use [imageSet](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/imageset-class.html):

```
images = imageSet('C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\train\');
```

This will create an object containing paths to all image files in the `train` directory, regardless of format. Then you can read the `i`-th image like this:

```
im = read(images, i);
```